# Element not interactable error in python ,selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

the code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
browser.maximize_window()
search = browser.find_element_by_name('search_query')
time.sleep(5)
search.send_keys("shakira waka waka")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 
time.sleep(5) 

browser.find_element_by_class_name("style-scope yt-img-shadow").click()
```

Hello friends, I want the video to play by searching the song names and the singer name generically on the youtube search section and clicking the image that comes after it. But the program gives "element not interactable" error. How can I play the video by clicking the incoming picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='search']"))).send_keys("shakira waka waka")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='search-icon-legacy']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ytd-video-renderer.style-scope.ytd-item-section-renderer"))).click()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the program is giving TimeoutException. I was wondering if it could actually be a generic code For example singer's name+ song's name> search on YouTube find song's picture > click the related song's picture> play the video

Comment: This is surprising, Cause it works just fine on my machine. It is generic code you just need to change the `send_keys("shakira waka waka")` part - you can give any singer name + song name.. shouldn't be an issue.. I have edited my code, please try again